# How to update only specific widgets in a StreamBuilder connected to a Firebase Database after certain times?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have a FirebaseAnimatedList as a todolist of items each with its own timestamp and other variables. In, for example, 5 minutes the UI of one of the widgets has to be rebuilt, and for another widget it could be in 8 minutes, etc.

My current solution is to have a timer that runs a function every 15 seconds to compare the timestamp of every Widget in the FirebaseAnimatedList to the current timestamp, but this can't be efficient especially as the list grows in size.

How would I go about updating only the items that need to be updated, with minimal data processing (eg. I don't want to have to go through every item in a giant list of data)?

Edit: I've switched over to a StreamBuilder connected to a Firebase Database stream for more control over the data before it hits the UI, the problem is the same however

Comment: You can use a steam builder that  listen for document change then  returns the firebase animated list based on the document change

Comment: Post your code for more help

Comment: I'm already checking for a document change, I'm trying to figure out how to update existing data based on the changing time

Comment: If you use stream builder it will rebuild the list each time any documents changes

Comment: If you have a timestamp of when it's supposed to change then couldn't you set the data to do something at that specific time? So parse through the data upon receipt and setup timers for each component that needs to be rebuilt based off the difference between the time you get the data and the time it needs to change. This is assuming I'm understanding your question and setup correctly.

Comment: @AdrianMurray while I'm sure a timer for each individual component would work, it seems like it would be inefficient.

Comment: I made the suggestion based off the fact that you’re doing a timer every 15 seconds. I don’t think you have a choice if your list is going to update based off of time... you have to have some way to tell that the particular time has passed. Which... would require some way to tell of a particular time. At least with my solution you only have to call a timer for each day point rather than an arbitrary 15 second timer. You could even do a relative time map and have a function check for the next time stamp once the last one runs through then start from that point.

Comment: @AdrianMurray so do a sort of priority queue where I only have to check the top one in the list?

Comment: exactly. Then you only need one timer and it goes off only when it needs to.

Comment: Okay thanks well put that as an answer and if I don't get anything else in the next day or two I'll mark that as correct